# nginx proxy_pass doesn't work to localhost

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I have my node app running locally on port 3000, I've set up nginx but for some reason it doesn't work right.

I tried to proxy_pass to http://google.com and it worked, but when I change it to http://localhost:3000 I get the nginx error page.

the app is running, i opened port 3000 on my server and I can access it on my http://domain:3000.

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    listen       [::]:80;
    server_name  mydomain.com;
    # root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
            proxy_pass "http://localhost:3000";
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

any idea why the proxying doesn't work properly?

Thanks.

Comment: are you doing it on ec2 server? if yes, `wget -q -O - 'http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4'`, and use the private IP it generates instead of `localhost`

Comment: it was SElinux issue.

Comment: @dor272, please add a detailed answer as to what you did and what the issue was. May be it will help someone in future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was SELinux issue - blocked http requests.

this command solved it:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
```